# VS code formatting breaks the code unexpectedly in .js files

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie in React. I am using vscode. Whenever I save app.js file, it formats the whole code and throws errors. [image: screenshot]

I tried reinstalling vscode. I am also not using any formatting extensions. Where is it getting wrong?

Comment: you could try installing `prettier` and then add some basic rules to `package.json` and it should sort it out for you

Comment: Change language mode (Ctrl+K, M) to "JavaScript React".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you are comfortable with keyboard shortcuts refer following steps:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings > User > Text Editor > Formatting

Uncheck format on save option.

I would also recommend using prettier extension.

- Install Prettier extensions
- Open any file and Right click in the content area
- Click Format document with and choose prettier

Comment: I had the same problem, but all the formatting settings are disabled. :( Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer already mentioned, a prettier extension could solve the issue, but fundamentally this is because the VScode reads the program as **js** instead of **Jsx**. You can select the right language from the bottom panel as you can see from the image. So for the sake of it, I'll post how I do it as well.

[image]

Once you click that, a command pallet will open asking you to choose the language you want. Type react and choose the first option. This will clear the issues and read the program as JSX and all snippets if not working will function as well.

[image]